# 'str' object has no attribute 'mime' error?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, email

Below  is  my code. Email.xlsx has columns  Name and Email. Values of the  column Name, match some Excel file names in the same  folder. Idea is to send an  email with attachments(Excel Workbooks) to a matching  email address in Email.xlsx. For example:-

Email.xlsx

```
Name Email 
1001 xxx@gmail.com
1002 yyy@gmail.com
1003 xxx@xxx.com
```

Files in the folder:

```
1001.xlsx
1002.xlsx
1004.xlsx
1005.xlsx
```

Expectation is  to send  emails  to xxx@gmail.com and yyy@gmail.com only with  1001.xlsx and 1002.xlsx as attachments respectively. They are the only matching names. My code is  below and it gives me this error: -

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mime'
```

Any pointers to where  I'm not doing things  right?

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

email_list = pd.read_excel(r'Email.xlsx')
folder_path="." #Same  folder as above 
my_files=[{each_file.split(".")[0]:each_file} for each_file in os.listdir(folder_path) if each_file.endswith(".xlsx")]
my_files_dict = dict(ChainMap(*my_files))

names = email_list['Name']
emails = email_list['Email']
 
for i in range(len(emails)): # iterate through the records
    # for every record get the name and the email addresses
    
    name = str(names[i])
    email = emails[i]
 
    if my_files_dict.get(name):
        smtp_ssl_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
        smtp_ssl_port = 465
        email_from = "xxxxx@gmail.com"
        email_pass = "xxxx"
        email_to = email
        msg2 = MIMEMultipart()
        msg2['Subject'] = "Record(s)"
        msg2['From'] = email_from
        msg2['To'] = email
        filename = my_files_dict.get(name)
        print(filename)
        attach = email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(filename.read(),_subtype="xlsx")
        msg.attach(attach)
        s2 = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_ssl_host, smtp_ssl_port)
        s2.login(email_from, email_pass)  
        s2.send_message(msg)
        s2.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have renamed the `email` package over here:

```
email = emails[i]
```

You're trying to refer to `from email.mime.text import MIMEText` but you're referring to the string `email` instead. Just change the name of the string and you're good

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer then?

Comment: Sure Shubham. Done it.